# Cannot access Ajax JSON data objects

Tags: ajax, json, extjs

I have a JSON response returning from an Ajax call but cannot seem to access any part of the JSON at all.

The JSON format is:
[{"id":"1","description":"Employee","coverage":"Center","covered":"X"}]

I have tried the following and nothing works:

```
success: function(result, request){
    jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
    var id = jsonData.id;
    alert(id);
 }

 * returns as undefined

success: function(result,request){
    jsonData = result.responseText  ##shows the Json perfectly
    alert(jsonData.length) ### displays as number of chars, not how many objects in json string
}
```

Comment: what do you see if in the first sample you would just `alert(jsonData)`?

Comment: Also I believe it's just Ext.JSON.decode not Ext.util.JSON.decode

Comment: first sample I get [Object, object] returned. I am using Extjs 3.4 so it's Ext.util.JSON.decode. I only see the data returned if I do alert(result.responseText)

Comment: Then looks like it's getting properly parsed in the first example. Add console.log(jsonData) to see full object in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ext.util.JSON.decode` is ExtJS3 method and `Ext.JSON.decode` is in ExtJS4, as you have not indicated which version of ExtJS you are using so failsafe way will be to use `Ext.decode` which is available in both ExtJS3 and ExtJS4

```
success: function(result, request){
    jsonData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

Comment: that returned [Object, object]

Comment: and if you do `alert(jsonData[0]["id"]);` then what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You may use "evil" `eval` for this:

```
var jsonData;
eval('jsonData =' + result.responseText);
alert(jsonData[0].id);
```

Comment: that returned undefined for the alert

Comment: Sorry, should be `alert(jsonData[0].id)`.