# Populate a form from store in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

I have used the following code to load data from my store to a form in ExtJs, but i am not able to retrieve the data to my textfield.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
       title: 'Form Panel',
       width: 350,
       height: 200,
       style: 'margin: 50px',
       renderTo: 'musicianProfile', // the name of the div in my JSP
       reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
           type: 'json',
           root: 'data',             
           fields: [
                    {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'lastName', type: 'string'}
                ]
       }),     
       items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                 fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'firstName',
                 readOnly: true,
                 flex: 1,
            }, {
                 fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'lastName',
                 readOnly: true,
                 flex: 1,
             }]
     }]
    });
    formPanel.getForm().load({
        method:'GET',
        url:'ajax/viewMusicianMembers.htm' //URL that produces a JSON result
    });
});
```

The value that i receive to my browser is:

```
{
     "success":true,"total":1,"message":null,
     "data":[{"firstName":"System","lastName":"Administrator"}],
     "errors":null
}
```

Can anyone help me to find out where the mistake is, and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

```
formPanel.getForm().load({
    method:'GET',
    url:'ajax/viewMusicianMembers.htm', //URL that produces a JSON result
    success: function(response, options) {
      formPanel.getForm().setValues(Ext.JSON.decode(response.data));
    },
    failure: function (response, options) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear friend, I was not able to get the output or able to view any difference when trying to use this code.  Also when i tried to get the data using an alert("response data: " + response.data); i get an undefined value.

Comment: Try debugging with firebug and try to get what is present in response when the request is success or fail

Comment: In firebug I get the following for the response.. {"success":true,"total":1,"message":null,"data":[{"firstName":"System","lastName":"Administrator"}],"errors":null}

Comment: You have 'data' in response, then how will response.data be undefined!!.. Get response.data to a variable which will be an array. pass that array to setValues() of form. Hope some thing will pop up.

Comment: I use >> var myDatas = response.data;
alert(myDatas[0]); >> to print the first element of the array but still I get myDatas[0] as an undefined value the popup.

Comment: can you try with var myDatas = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.data)

Comment: It now says Ext.util.JSON is undefined.. :(

Comment: Ext.JSON.decode() is in ExtJS 4. Sorry i mentioned in ExtJS 3 specific in my previous comment

Comment: my form load is 
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
formPanel.getForm().load({
   method:'GET',
   url:'ajax/viewMusicianMembers.htm', 
   success: function(response, options) {
     var myData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.data);
        alert(myData);
   },
   failure: function (response, options) {
   }
});
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

and the response in firebug is
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
{"success":true,"total":1,"message":null,"data":[{"firstName":"System","lastName":"Administrator"}],"errors":null}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

still the alert popup is producing an undefined value..

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143516/cannot-access-ajax-json-data-objects